# Unity 3d тачскрин вместо мыши в Match3

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть Match3 игрушка. Для мышки код был (скрипт висит на кубике, объект кубик для всех одинаковый, только цвет меняем ))

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
//само действие
}
```

Работает. Попробовал для тачпада сделать так

```
public void fortouch()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
// само действие
}}
```

сам fortouch вешаем в Update. Когда запускаем игру, по нажатию на экран выделяется сразу большая куча кубиков, хотя в Array место только для двоих.

Вопрос собственно такой - как сделать на тачскрине такие же прикосновения как если бы это был щелчок мышкой? Ресурсы для всех кубиков одинаковые, отличаются они только цветами, может в этом загвоздка нерабочести моего кода для тача? Когда не было на сцене кучи одинаковых объектов, он вроде нормально работал. Но мышке же это не мешает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш скрипт проверяет только что имеется хоть одно касание и оно в фазе начало тача. Если вы хотите отлавливать событие на объектах то в идеале надо проходить по всем прикосновениям, пускать луч из точки наблюдения через точку касания и проверять в какой объект он попадает через физику. Вот нашел в инете пример, вешаем его на любой объект и он будет проверять и вызывать OnMouseDown на всех объектах где был Тач. Только учтите, что используется физика, поэтому на всех объектах которые должны находиться должен присутствовать коллайдер.

```
void Update()
{
 foreach(Touch t in Input.Touches)
 {
     if(t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
     {
         Vector3 point = new Vector3(t.position.x, t.position.y, 0);
         Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(point);
         RaycastHit hit;
         if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
         {
             hit.collider.SendMessage("OnMouseDown", null, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
         }
     }
  }  
 }
```